# Can't add the first column during parsing in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new in Python, I'm trying to do parsing to the following text, but I can't add the first column in case it was empty.
If the 1st column is empty, the code should get the value from the above row.

The input is as shown:

```
7724    79G7P42             TTP7R_MxT72   Test-Failed                  
7729    79M7M7S             TTP7R_MxT74   Test-Failed                  
        77G2P72             TTP7R_MxT75   Test-Failed                  
        79G7P22             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed                  
7760    78D07A7             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed                  
7763    78D07B3   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Failed                  
7775    77A2I7R             TTP7R_CxT75   Test-Failed                  
        77A2I2R             TTP7R_CxT73   Test-Failed                  
        77A0I3R             TTP7R_CxT76   Test-Failed                  
        74A7I4R   AVA       TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed                 
7646    77R2G7M   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT78   Test-Passed                 
7648    77R2G2M             TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed                 
7973    77C2M7S             TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Passed
```

The output should be as shown:-

```
7724    79G7P42             TTP7R_MxT72   Test-Failed                  
7729    79M7M7S             TTP7R_MxT74   Test-Failed                  
7729    77G2P72             TTP7R_MxT75   Test-Failed                  
7729    79G7P22             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed                  
7760    78D07A7             TTP7R_MxT77   Test-Failed                  
7763    78D07B3   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Failed                  
7775    77A2I7R             TTP7R_CxT75   Test-Failed                  
7775    77A2I2R             TTP7R_CxT73   Test-Failed                  
7775    77A0I3R             TTP7R_CxT76   Test-Failed                  
7775    74A7I4R   AVA       TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed                 
7646    77R2G7M   UNAVA     TTP7R_CxT78   Test-Passed                 
7648    77R2G2M             TTP7R_CxT74   Test-Passed                 
7973    77C2M7S             TTP7R_CxT79   Test-Passed
```

Here is the code that I prepared.

```
    with open('dio.txt') as f:
          for line in f:
            x=(line[0:5].strip())
            y=(line[8:17].strip())
            z=(line[18:25].strip())
            u=(line[28:39].strip())
            v=(line[42:60].strip()) 
            print(x   ,y   ,z   ,u   ,v)
```

Please your support.

2. Now the output is string. how can I put the output as a list?

Comment: `thelist = []` before your `with open(...)` then replace your `print(...)` with `thelist.append((x, y, z, u, v))`.

Comment: What defines a "column"? You shouldnt rely on spaces alone to help identify that

Comment: You appear to have a fixed-width column file, and [pandas would be best for that](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: @OneCricketeer The file has some lines in the beginning which I'd like to exclude , and start parsing after a specific line. I'd like start after the line contain (Value     Node ....).

Comment: After `open('dio.txt') as f:`  you can call `next(f)` to skip a line. Keep calling to skip many

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is working in case of I know how many lines shown I move. This is not fixed number. The step I need, In case the code find a line start with (Value     Node), then go to next line then start parsing.  Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save off the first non-empty string in the corresponding column. When you do get an empty string, then re-assign it to the previously non-empty one.

```
l = []
prev_x = ''
with open('dio.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        x = line[0:5].strip()
        if x:
            prev_x = x
        else:
            x = prev_x
        y = line[8:17].strip()
        z = line[18:25].strip()
        u = line[28:39].strip()
        v =  line[42:60].strip() 
        l.append([x,y,z,u,v])

for line in l:
    print('\t'.join(line))
```

### Output

```
7724    79G7P42     TTP7R_MxT72 Test-Failed
7729    79M7M7S     TTP7R_MxT74 Test-Failed
7729    77G2P72     TTP7R_MxT75 Test-Failed
7729    79G7P22     TTP7R_MxT77 Test-Failed
7760    78D07A7     TTP7R_MxT77 Test-Failed
7763    78D07B3 UNAVA   TTP7R_CxT79 Test-Failed
7775    77A2I7R     TTP7R_CxT75 Test-Failed
7775    77A2I2R     TTP7R_CxT73 Test-Failed
7775    77A0I3R     TTP7R_CxT76 Test-Failed
7775    74A7I4R AVA TTP7R_CxT74 Test-Passed
7646    77R2G7M UNAVA   TTP7R_CxT78 Test-Passed
7648    77R2G2M     TTP7R_CxT74 Test-Passed
7973    77C2M7S     TTP7R_CxT79 Test-Passed
```

Answer (score 0):

try it,

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
     _id = None
     for line in f:
         record = line.split(' ')
         if record[0].isnumeric():
             _id =  record[0]
         else:
             record.insert(0, _id)
         print(' '.join(record).replace('\n', ''))
```

result:

```
7724 79G7P42 TTP7R_MxT72 Test-Failed
7729 79M7M7S TTP7R_MxT74 Test-Failed
7729 77G2P72 TTP7R_MxT75 Test-Failed
7729 79G7P22 TTP7R_MxT77 Test-Failed
7760 78D07A7 TTP7R_MxT77 Test-Failed
7763 78D07B3 UNAVA TTP7R_CxT79 Test-Failed
7775 77A2I7R TTP7R_CxT75 Test-Failed
7775 77A2I2R TTP7R_CxT73 Test-Failed
7775 77A0I3R TTP7R_CxT76 Test-Failed
7775 74A7I4R AVA TTP7R_CxT74 Test-Passed
7646 77R2G7M UNAVA TTP7R_CxT78 Test-Passed
7648 77R2G2M TTP7R_CxT74 Test-Passed
7973 77C2M7S TTP7R_CxT79 Test-Passed
```

Comment: ,is it possible to contact you, there are some modification to be added to the code. wma_76 at yahoo.